# DrawRectangle goes out of form bounds

Tags: c#, graphics, rectangles

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        g = e.Graphics;
        blockList.DrawBlocksInList(g);  //Drawing the blocks that were added to the list in the Form1_Load below;
        g.FillRectangle(MainBlock._Pen.Brush, MainBlock._Rectangle);  //Drawing the Main Block;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float rectSize = this.Width / 10.0f;    //What the size of each rectangle should be, depending on the form's size;
        Block BlockForList; //No need to initialize it;
        for (float y = 0; y < this.Height; y += rectSize)   //500 is the size of the Form, 50 is the size of the X & Y of each rectangle;
            for (float x = 0; x < this.Width; x += rectSize)
            {
                BlockForList = new Block(pen, new RectangleF(x, y, rectSize, rectSize)); //Initializing the block each time to set different locations;
                blockList.list.Add(BlockForList);   //Adding the blocks to the list to draw them all;
            }
    }
```

After that I use a method to draw all the blocks in the blockList.list, but this happens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGNLt.jpg

Comment: Well, you are doing it wrong and did not post the correct code.  Whatever Graphics object you used to draw was not created correctly.  Use e.Graphics in the Paint event handler.

Comment: I did assign the graphics object to the graphics object in the Paint event handler. If I didn't do that no rectangles would show up anyways, you can see that in the picture I provided :P (will fix the link to it now cuz the link is broken it seems).
Edited the code to show the graphics object assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, it will go out of bounds - you've told it to allow the left edge of each block to go up to `Width`, and the right edge to go up to `Height`.

Do you want this?

```
    for (float y = 0; y < this.Height-rectSize; y += rectSize)   //500 is the size of the Form (this.Width & this.Height), 50 (rectSize) is the size of the X & Y of each rectangle (basically squares);
        for (float x = 0; x < this.Width-rectSize; x += rectSize)
```

--

### edit

ah - Also in the paint you first need to call the `base` `OnPaint()` method.
That will fill the background in.

Comment: Ahhh yes! What a basic mistake ;-;
Thank you for helping <3

Comment: call the onPaint() method within the Paint event? I do that by using this.invalidate() or base.onPaint(e), right? but that would case an infinite loop since onPaint() will trigger the Paint event which calls the onPaint() again.

Comment: I used {y <= this.Height - rectSize; & x <= this.Width - rectSize;} for anyone who reads this looking for an answer ^-^